# Query on date for posts created the last 24h

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have this schema with a date for the field "created_at":

```
var post = new mongoose.Schema({
    text : String,
    created_at : {type : Date, index : true},
    pos : {latitude: Number, longitude: Number},
    created_by : {type : Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref : "UserSchema"}
});
```

With this:

```
Post.pre("save", function (next){
    var currentDate = new Date();

    if(!this.created_at)
    {
        this.created_at = currentDate;
    }
    next();
});
```

Now I only want post created last 24h, how can I query this ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To get posts created in the last 24hrs, you could get the current time, subtract 24 hours and get the value of start date to use in your date range query:

```
var start = new Date(new Date().getTime() - (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));

Post.find({ "created_at": { "$gte": start } }).exec(callback);
```

If you want to know more about `$gte`, check the following article:

> https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/gte/

---

With the **[momentjs](http://momentjs.com/)** library this can be simply

```
var start = moment().subtract(24, 'hours').toDate();
Post.find({ "created_at": { "$gte": start } }).exec(callback);
```

You could also define a date [default](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/defaults.html) with a function instead of the pre hook middleware:

```
var post = new mongoose.Schema({
    text : String,
    created_at : {type : Date, default: Date.now, index : true},
    pos : {latitude: Number, longitude: Number},
    created_by : {type : Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref : "UserSchema"}
});
```

Comment: I tried this: var start = moment().substract(1, "day"); but this throw an error "undefined is not a function".

Comment: @JohnyBro Did you require the moment object first before using it? Did you also try using the native JavaScript date objects approach?

Comment: Yes I use require and no i didn't try with the native date objects cause I will need momentjs later I think.

Comment: It work with the native Date object but will be nice if I can use momentJS.

Comment: @JohnyBro it's `days` not `day`

Answer (score -4):

I have try following code for date range in php+mongodb and its working fine so try like this.

```
$time1 = new DateTime('Your Date');
$from = new MongoDate($time1->getTimestamp());
$check_date = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($filter_data['to']));
```

Your Condition is look like this

```
'created_on'=>array($gt' => $check_date)
```